# Fourier Transform of Rectangular Impulse Function possible in specific Form?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

[Rectangular Impulse Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPIcQ.png)

The above Rectangular Impulse Function is given. It's height is $A$ and it's width is $T$.

The question is the following:

If the Fourier Transform of the above function is in the form of $$F(ω)=X*si(ωT)$$
what is $X$?

I tried it and I can't seem to be able to find a constant $X$ to describe the Fourier Transform in the wanted form. If you look up any table, the answer would be the following: $$F(ω)=A*T*si(ω*T/2)$$

I do not think it is possible to define a constant $X$ that would be able to turn $$si(ω*T/2)$$ into $$si(ωT)$$ since it's outside of the si input arguments. Am I right? Is it possible to define $X$?

Comment: The Fourier transform of $A \ 1_{|t|< T/2} $ is $A\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} e^{-i \omega t} dt = A\frac{e^{-i \omega t}}{-i \omega} |_{-T/2}^{T/2} =A\frac{e^{-i \omega T/2}-e^{i \omega T/2}}{-i \omega} =A \frac{-2i \sin(\omega T/2)}{-i \omega}$

Comment: I know that. I have the same solution in my original question. It's just simplified further than your answer. Your comment doesn't answer my question.